# MySQL not the expected output - YEAR() won't work

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have a problem with a query which dosen't output what I expects and I cant get it to work.

The query is

```
SELECT COUNT(event_type_id), userprofiles.id as userprofile_id, users.first_name, users.last_name 
FROM users, userprofiles
            LEFT JOIN event_matches ON event_matches.userprofile_id = userprofiles.id
            AND event_type_id = 1
            LEFT JOIN activities ON activities.id = event_matches.activity_id
            AND YEAR(activities.start) = 2012
            WHERE userprofiles.home_id = 2
            AND users.id = userprofiles.user_id
            GROUP BY userprofiles.id
            ORDER BY COUNT(event_type_id) DESC
```

But when I run this query it gets all the activities and not only the ones from 2012, it seems like the LEFT JOIN does something. If i dont use LEFT JOIN and instead use JOIN, the query works, but then I only get the user who has a event_type_id = 1 in 2012. But the reason why I used the LEFT JOIN is because I want to have alle the users, and not only the ones who has a event_type_id.

Hopes someone can see my mistake and help me.

Comment: Try changing the query to use consistent `join` syntax throughout -- that is, fix the join between `user` and `userprofiles`.

Comment: move this condition "AND YEAR(activities.start) = 2012" to your where clause and try again.  In fact... dont use AND in either of your joins.  move both to where and see if that resolves your issues.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - if I do this, it will only return the user which has a record in 2012, but what I want is to get all the users, but order it  by the users who has most records in 2012. So I want all the users, thats why I tried to use LEFT JOIN.

Comment: @drewlander - the same thing as my comment above:-(

Comment: Gotcha.  And you tried just changing the left join for the year to an inner join and leaving the eventid as a left join?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what -- in English are you trying to get...  Ex: For all user profiles where home_id = 2, how many events of type 1 were within 2012.  By doing left joins, you are saying I want all profiles of Home_ID = 2 regardless of attending an event of type 1.  You would want to change them from LEFT JOINs to just JOIN (INNER JOIN) if that is the case

This is for all user profiles regardless of an actual event that was of type 1 within 2012, this only cares if it finds an event of type 1

```
SELECT 
      COUNT(event_type_id), 
      userprofiles.id as userprofile_id, 
      users.first_name, 
      users.last_name 
   FROM 
      userprofiles
         JOIN users
            ON userprofiles.user_id = users.id
         LEFT JOIN event_matches 
            ON userprofiles.id = event_matches.userprofile_id
            AND event_matches.event_type_id = 1
            LEFT JOIN activities 
               ON event_matches.activity_id = activities.id 
               AND YEAR(activities.start) = 2012
   WHERE 
      userprofiles.home_id = 2
   GROUP BY 
      userprofiles.id
   ORDER BY 
      COUNT(event_type_id) DESC
```

by changing to the granular activity table, you would get your count of event types = 1 AND the year was of 2012

```
SELECT 
      COUNT(activities.id), 
      ... rest of query...
  ORDER BY 
      COUNT(activities.id) DESC
```

If you only want those profiles that actually HAD events of type 1 in the year 2012, change to JOIN

```
SELECT 
      COUNT(event_type_id), 
      userprofiles.id as userprofile_id, 
      users.first_name, 
      users.last_name 
   FROM 
      userprofiles
         JOIN users
            ON userprofiles.user_id = users.id
         JOIN event_matches 
            ON userprofiles.id = event_matches.userprofile_id
            AND event_matches.event_type_id = 1
            JOIN activities 
               ON event_matches.activity_id = activities.id 
               AND YEAR(activities.start) = 2012
   WHERE 
      userprofiles.home_id = 2
   GROUP BY 
      userprofiles.id
   ORDER BY 
      COUNT(event_type_id) DESC
```